# failed to accept an incoming connection: from [HOST IP]: TLS connection has been closed during handshake

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am having "failed to accept an incoming connection: from [HOST IP]: TLS connection has been closed during handshake" error in Zabbix Server's log after configuring Zabbix Active Agents with PSK encryption.

Outout of Zabbix_Sender command seems okay:
info from server: "processed: 1; failed: 0; total: 1; seconds spent: 0.00090"

Availability of all Hosts in Zabbix Server Configuration page are green as well.

[[image: Zabbix Hosts Availability in Configuration Page [1]]

Did I do anything wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Did you configure encryption in the agent configuration file? What parameters are set? If you check the server logfile, does the error message give any additional detail?

Comment: @Richlv, Below is configuration of the agent and server error message: 

Agent Configuration:
PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log
LogFileSize=0
DebugLevel=3
StartAgents=0
ServerActive=IP of Zabbix Server
Hostname=Agent5
RefreshActiveChecks=60
Timeout=30
Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/
TLSConnect=psk
TLSAccept=psk
TLSPSKIdentity=PSK34
TLSPSKFile=/etc/zabbix/PSKKeyOfAgent

Zabbix Server Error:
failed to accept an incoming connection: from [IP of Agent] TLS connection has been closed during handshake::

Comment: Is that error message trimmed? Is PSK identity set to "PSK34" in the host properties of that host? Does the PSK key in the agent PSK file match the one configured in the host properties?

Comment: @Richlv, The error message is trimmed and PSK34 is same as configured in the agent and host properties of that host in Zabbix hosts configuration page. Any hints to solve the problem?

Comment: What's the full error line in the server log? Noticed that agent is configured to require PSK for incoming connections while server uses no encryption - but it should not be related to the error you are getting. Any files in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/` that could override connection related parameters?

Comment: @Richlv, that is the only error I had besides of the date and time stamp in Zabbix Server. The issue looks like resolved by itself after I changed the hostname and psk in zabbix server's zabbix agent and after restarting the server. Not sure if that is the root cause of the problem. Thanks for your time and effort to help me out.